# can't get right div to extend the length of the container div

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with this for awhile and can't get the right div to extend to the end of the caption container. Can anyone help me out?

```
.rightcontent{
width:60%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7kbcnyop/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property:

```
float:right;
```

to the css. Your code should be:

```css
.captioncontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.leftcontent {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #33adff;
  float: left;
}
.rightcontent {
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #66ff99;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="captioncontainer">
  <div class="leftcontent">
    <h1>핫요가 효능</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a libero quam. Aliquam volutpat vitae sem sed euismod. Donec a congue ipsum, id sollicitudin orci. Donec neque lectus, elementum non sem sit amet, suscipit sollicitudin quam. Fusce molestie
    dictum turpis nec posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed ut ex
  </div>
  <div class="rightcontent">
    Etiam venenatis lobortis felis nec euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam faucibus elit nec maximus consectetur. Morbi interdum arcu at enim consectetur, tempor sollicitudin quam vehicula. Fusce urna lectus, dapibus maximus nulla vitae, dictum tristique
    justo. Maecenas porta elementum risus sed mollis. Sed tellus ligula, semper at odio ut, accumsan rutrum diam.

  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arnavb11/u2jppjtw/)

Comment: This is a very well explained answer +1 upvote. And someone else copied your answer.

Comment: You probably want to remove the recommandation to use `table` elements for layouting purposes. this is a bad practice since it exists. And why would the usage of `float` not be a good recommandation?

Comment: Thanks Arnav, that was it!  I appreciate your suggestion for using tables however, I am just starting to create layouts for web pages and read that tables should not be used for layouts and that divs should be used in place of them but from your example I can see the advantage of using tables vs divs+floats. Thanks again

Comment: If you feel that this answer is correct, then mark it so by clicking the green checkmark icon next to answer, currently gray, to mark it correct. @mkng07

Comment: I've upvoted this answer but since I have fewer than 15 reputation points, it doesn't display publicly :( @JamesCalder

Comment: @mkng07 not asking to upvote it, but click the grey checkmark icon below the downvote arrow. It will turn green on click. That will mark it correct. This is so if someone in the future sees this answers, they can know what to look for.

Comment: `Float` element should **NOT** be used for this.

Comment: @YashJain why not?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code. [Click Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/7kbcnyop/6/)

As @Pragyakar Joshi states,

> Why do you have the width set to 60%? Doesn't setting it to 100% solve the problem?

This does indeed solve the problem.

Take a look at this snippet.

```css
.captioncontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.leftcontent {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #33adff;
  float: left;
}

.rightcontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #66ff99;
}
```

```html
<div class="captioncontainer">
  <div class="leftcontent">
    <h1>핫요가 효능</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a libero quam. Aliquam volutpat vitae sem sed euismod. Donec a congue ipsum, id sollicitudin orci. Donec neque lectus, elementum non sem sit amet, suscipit sollicitudin quam. Fusce molestie
    dictum turpis nec posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed ut ex
  </div>
  <div class="rightcontent">
    Etiam venenatis lobortis felis nec euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam faucibus elit nec maximus consectetur. Morbi interdum arcu at enim consectetur, tempor sollicitudin quam vehicula. Fusce urna lectus, dapibus maximus nulla vitae, dictum tristique
    justo. Maecenas porta elementum risus sed mollis. Sed tellus ligula, semper at odio ut, accumsan rutrum diam.

  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Replacing `height: 200px;` with `height: 350px;` looks better.

```css
.captioncontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.leftcontent {
  width: 40%;
  height: 350px;
  background: #33adff;
  float: left;
}

.rightcontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background: #66ff99;
}
```

```html
<div class="captioncontainer">
  <div class="leftcontent">
    <h1>핫요가 효능</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a libero quam. Aliquam volutpat vitae sem sed euismod. Donec a congue ipsum, id sollicitudin orci. Donec neque lectus, elementum non sem sit amet, suscipit sollicitudin quam. Fusce molestie
    dictum turpis nec posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed ut ex
  </div>
  <div class="rightcontent">
    Etiam venenatis lobortis felis nec euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam faucibus elit nec maximus consectetur. Morbi interdum arcu at enim consectetur, tempor sollicitudin quam vehicula. Fusce urna lectus, dapibus maximus nulla vitae, dictum tristique
    justo. Maecenas porta elementum risus sed mollis. Sed tellus ligula, semper at odio ut, accumsan rutrum diam.

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you think this solved the problem, please mark it correct for people in the future to see(hit the gray check mark which turns green)